# De Bruijn's inequality for series

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

According to [Mitrinović](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-99970-3_3?noAccess=true), 3.9.42. page 359, N.G. De Bruijn proved the following result.

Let $f$ be a decreasing and positive function such that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} f(n)$ converges and let $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{k}$ be positive with $a_{1}^{-1}+\cdots +a_{k}^{-1}=1$.
Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} f\left(n a_{1}\right)+\cdots+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} f\left(n a_{k}\right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} f(n).
$$

I am looking for a proof of this inequality (ideally De Bruijn's).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a reference, but here is a possible proof:

For positive integers $N, n$ and $j \in \{ 1, \ldots, k \}$ holds the following implication:
$$
 f(na_j) > f(N) \implies na_j < N \implies n < \frac{N}{a_j} \, .
$$
It follows that the number of pairs $(n, j)$ with $f(na_j) > f(N)$ is less than
$$
 \frac{N}{a_1} + \cdots  + \frac{N}{a_k} = N \, .
$$

Therefore one can rearrange the numbers $(f(n a_j))_{n, j}$ into a non-increasing sequence $(y_m)_m$, and that sequence satifies $y_m \le f(m)$. Then
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n a_j) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty y_m \le \sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m) \, .
$$